# Is there a better way to work with WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

This is a question I asked myself many times. My company uses WebForms, and always I start developing a new application, my problem is managing controls state. With control state I mean things like: "If this ListBox is empty, disable this button, if this GridView is in edit mode and there is a row selected, disable that TextBox, if this button is pressed, refill the DetailsView, etc." Normally, when I finish coding the WebForms application, I have written a lot of code to control all those controls state in the same Page, and that code is messy and error prone. Are there any tecnics I can apply for improving and order the Page's code (distributing it in other clases, for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen some examples of WebForms code where the pages state is controlled using the [MVP (Model-View-Presenter) pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter).

The MVP pattern is a variant of the MVC pattern where you have a Presenter class that controls the state of you page. It allows you to extract the code that controls state into a class that is both testable and reusable.

Moving to the MVP pattern if you have used "traditional" WebForms for a while can be challenging, but it will give you much cleaner code if you do it right.

An old but ok article on WebForms and MVP can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff955232.aspx

You should also google the concept, there are many articles on the subject out there. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can make it more cleaner using custom userControls.

It's reusable and the code logic is not in your "master" page